# MATLAB (.NET Assembly) Data type question: MWArray to string conversion

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-deployment

I am using MATLAB's integrated .NET assembly builder but I am having an issue with data types and return values.

I have compiled a small, very simple, function in MATLAB and build it for .NET.

I am able to call the namespace and even the function just fine. However, my function returns a string value, and MATLAB defaults to returning it as an MWArray object data type. However, I know that the value is a string but I can't figure out how to cast it.

My MATLAB function looks like this:

```
function version = get_version()
    foo ='1.0';
    bar = strcat('foo-', foo);

    version = string(bar);
end
```

And then in .NET I call it as:

```
MWArray version;
version = xClass.get_version();
```

whereas xClass is the name of the MATLAB built class. When I try to cast it into a string:

```
string str = version.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

I just receive:

```
Internal_Matrix_Reference____
```

but not **foo-1.0** as I would expect.

Does anyone have experience with the .NET builder in MATLAB that can help me with this? It is really throwing me for a loop.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the solution is pretty easy. The Matlab function has to return the version differently:

```
function version = get_version()
    foo ='1.0';
    version = strcat('foo-', foo);
end
```

And then in .NET it works as expected:

```
MWArray version;
version = xClass.get_version();

string str = version.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str);
```